# Checkout a specific commit with NodeGit

Tags: node.js, git, nodegit

I have a NodeGit repository object, `repo`, and a string `sha` code which represents a commit id, `commit_id`. How can I perform a git checkout of this commit using NodeGit, which would act the same as the command `git checkout $commit_id`?

So far, I have tried creating a `Reference` using the commit id and then using `checkoutRef` to check out the reference. However, the repository does not change and I get the error `Error: the given reference name '<my commit id>' is not valid`.

```
NodeGit.Reference.lookup(repo, commit_id, (reference) => {
    repo.checkoutRef(reference)
});
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The [nodegit documentation](https://www.nodegit.org/api/) seems to be a good source of information.

Comment: Hi @larsks - I have added my attempt to the question. The documentation does not provide any examples of checking out a commit ID, only the latest commit of a named branch. Thanks!

Comment: Agree, very confusing

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found so far is:

```
const commit = await repo.getCommit(commit_id);
await nodegit.Reset.reset(repo, commit, nodegit.Reset.TYPE.HARD);
```

But it's so slow... Especially for big repositories!